# Bootstrap DateTime-Picker: Start Date

Tags: datetime, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap DateTime Picker for my website.
There are two DateTimePickers (dt1 and dt2).
If dt1's value changes, the start date of dt2 should be set to that value.
**How can I realize this?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using [this](https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker/) date picker, you could do it like this.

```
$("#dateA").on('change', function () {
            var dateA = $("#dateA").data("datepicker").getDate();
            $("#dateB").data("datepicker").setStartDate(dateA);

        });
```

Comment: I think this will copy the value of `dateA` to `dateB`. OP wanted to change the `startDate` of the second dt.